# Magento - Unable to display custom options

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm using a module for displaying grouped configurable products and all options are showing except custom options. They are displaying on the configurable product page but that's it. I'm trying to use the code in `app\design\frontend\blank\blank\template\catalog\product\view\options.phtml` in my custom `configurable.phtml` but `$_options` is showing up `null`. Here is the code used to retrieve `$_options`

```
<?php $_options = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getOptions()) ?>
<?php if (count($_options)):?>
```

and after the javascript

```
    <?php foreach($_options as $_option): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getOptionHtml($_option) ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
    <?php else: echo dlkghflghf;?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The **dlkghflghf** is displaying so i know $_options is not showing up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your custom configurable.phtml is a template of what block? You can use a block that extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options or you can set your own method for options like the method from Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options, you also need to have a method getProduct():

```
public function getOptions()
{
    return $this->getProduct()->getOptions();
}
```

Comment: I tracked the block `class Brim_Groupedoptions_Model_Block_Container_Product_View_Options extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options
{
    protected function _construct()
    {

    }

    public function getOptions($product = null)
    {
        if ($product == null) {
            $product = $this->getProduct();
        }

        $options = array();
        foreach ($product->getProductOptionsCollection() as $option) {
            $option->setProduct($product);
            $options[] = $option;
        }

        return $options;
    }
}`

Comment: I don't know what that plugin is doing or is supposed to do, but as you can see those two methods are different. You should look further into the code, maybe it's a bug or just works a little different.